# Swift: conditional modifier for .font of text()

Tags: swift, properties, modifier

I am new with Swift an still learning. I tried to format a text based on a boolean variable. It works well with font size and style. But it won't work with styles like .bold() or .italic. Any idea how to do this? I tried ViewModifier too, but there is the same problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var txtFont = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Button("Toggle the Textproperty") {
                self.txtFont.toggle()
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .font(txtFont ? .largeTitle : .none)
                .bold()
                .italic()
//                txtFont ? .bold() : .none <= this line won't work
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

The same problem I have with changing the style of a picker from `DefaultPickerStyle` to `SegmentedPickerStyle` based on a boolean decision. I need this to get the Userinterface more user-friendly.

Any ideas How to realise this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should go with [.fontWeight(_ weight: Font.Weight?)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3276885-fontweight)

```
Text("Hello, World!")
       .fontWeight(txtFont ? .bold : .regular)
```

If you want to set multiple font properties at once, it's also easy as,

```
Text("Hello, World!")
            .font(txtFont ? .largeTitle.bold().italic() : .none)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I tried with ```.font(...)``` without result. But with ```.italic()``` it won't work, right?

Comment: Thank you very much. this helped me a lot to understand better how it works.